# How to configure PHP not to resolve symbolic links?

Tags: php, linux

My filesystem is designed to host all the projects in the following way:

```
/[path to server]/[client name]/[project name]
```

Every `/[client name]/[project name]` has a symlink that's constructed using a UUID (36 characters long code). Therefore, requests to `/[uuid]` resolve to an appropriate `/[client name]/[project name]`.

I am facing an issue at the PHP level. PHP automatically resolves any symbolic links to a realpath. Instead, I want PHP to use the symbolic path.

The underlying issue I am after is to protect client identities. Therefore, whether PHP exception is thrown, any error or `__FILE__`, or `__DIR__` value is dumped, it should contain the symbolic link rather than the realpath.

Is that configurable?

Comment: In a word, no. You should suppress all of those error messages in production though, so it shouldn't be an issue anyway.

Comment: @DaveRandom, unfortunately, I am expected to configure the server in such a way that dumping `__DIR__` or `__FILE__` or whatever else value for that reason, would give no idea of the original path.

Comment: Maybe something in Suhosin to do some of it (don't know for sure), but I highly doubt you would be able to affect the values of `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`. However if you *hard*link instead of symlink I imagine it will show the path you want it to and won't break anything (at least, nothing PHP related)

Comment: That means whoever told you to do so is stupid. Users should never see PHP errors and the application should not display absolute paths to the user

Comment: @DaveRandom That would be a solution, thought hard linking is not available for directories.

Comment: Oh right, temporary intelligence fail. Ignore that.

Comment: Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php (custom error handler) or this http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.ze1.zendapi.php (customising the php core).

Comment: (What i'm suggesting is to customize the error messages themselves)

Answer (score 1):

> Is that configurable?

No. You need to patch PHP source for that and recompile.

Maybe there is some chance (but I dunno how far that goes) by replacing the default `file://` stream wrapper. But probably not for the main script.